# How to install flash player Windows 7 64 bits?

Tags: windows-7, flash

How can I install flash player windows 7 64 bits? I've read the instructions and uninstall my old flash player with the uninstall tool but when I install the new player nothing happens and the browser plugin isn't installed? I've UAC disabled.

Comment: I wrote some info here .  The auto installer did not work for me. http://superuser.com/questions/344487/flash-player-11-installer-not-working-on-windows-7

Comment: Thanks, this link work: http://www.adobe.com/products/flashplayer/distribution3.html.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Which browser are you using?

There are two downloads, one for IE and one for Firefox.

Just point your browser to the download page and it will download the correct binaries.

edit:

Offline Installers.

http://www.adobe.com/support/flashplayer/downloads.html

Comment: I'm using firefox and this method doesn't work either. The browser prompt me to download the plugin but when I click there is already a page not found error in the dialog box and the browser refuse to install it automatically and point me to the manual install?

Comment: I'll edit my answer

Comment: I didn't tried your link because it's compiled with debug symbols, I tried this link http://www.adobe.com/products/flashplayer/distribution3.html.

Comment: Ack, Flash Player Download Center != Flash Player.  Lame.